# How do i write this code more pythonic way

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I am writing Django's views to check if a valid album id is provided or not. But it looks cumbersome and hard to read. I want to make it more readable and short. I cant directly check `data['id']`. It will give error if its blank.

```
def post(self, request):
    if len(request.body) > 0:
        data = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))
    else:
        return Response({'message': 'Album id is required'})

    if 'id' not in data:
        return Response({'message': 'Valid Album id is required'})

    try:
        id = int(data['id'])
        if id < 1:
            return Response({'message': 'Valid album id is required'})
        album = Album.objects.get(pk=id)
    except:
        return Response({'message': 'Valid album id is required'})
```

Comment: This code has one glaring issue that isn't about style: the bare `try: ... except: ...` What error are you actually *expecting* to catch there? You should always catch as specific an error as possible. As for pythonic: `if len(request.body) > 0:` should just be `if request.body:`

Comment: For readability, the *first line of order* is *use functions to encapsulate logic*.

Comment: Yeah. I have other similar views. so I will use functions to make it more readable.

Comment: You can add a specific error to your except

Answer (score 1):

The whole problem seems to be what to do when the `id` is not a valid entry in `data`.

Looking at your code, and particularly the part below, it seems that an `id` value less than 1 is invalid.

```py
 if id < 1:
    return Response({'message': 'Valid album id is required'})
```

Furthermore, the `try...except` means that, if `id` is not part of `data`, then that is also invalid.

This means your code could be simplified by using default values, as such:

```py
def post(self, request):
    if len(request.body) > 0:
        data = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))
    else:
        return Response({'message': 'Album id is required'})

    id = int(data.get('id', 0))
    if id < 1:
        return Response({'message': 'Valid album id is required'})
    album = Album.objects.get(pk=id)
    # f-strings below are a python 3
    return Response({'message': f'The album you have requested is {album}'})
```

The important part of the snippet above is: `data.get('id', 0)`
which returns `data['id']` if `id` is a valid field, and 0 if `id` is not found inside `data`

Unrelated, because both are valid ways of checking `request.body`, but the more pythonic way is to do it like @juanpa.arrivillaga suggested, namely:
`if request.body:`

To further simplify it, I would reduce some of the duplication by doing it this way:

```py
def post(self, request):
    if request.body:
        data = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))

        id = int(data.get('id', 0))
        if id < 1:
            return Response({'message': 'Valid album id is required'})
        album = Album.objects.get(pk=id)
        # f-strings below are a python 3
        return Response({'message': f'The album you have requested is {album}'})

    return Response({'message': 'Album id is required'})
```

Answer (score 1):

The biggest two things to keep in mind when trying to increase readability is *don't prematurely optimize* and *use functions to encapsulate logic* (especially if that logic may have to be re-used in the future).

So, just a quick example:

```
def post(self, request):
    if request.body:
        data = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))
    else:
        return Response({'message': 'Album id is required'})

    if _validate_data(data):
        id_ = int(data['id'])
        album = Album.objects.get(pk=id_)
        # probably want to return a Response as well...
    else:
        return Response({'message': 'Valid Album id is required'})


def _validate_data(data):
    if 'id' not in data:
        return False
    try:
        id_ = int(data['id'])
    except ValueError:
        return False
    return id_ >= 1
```

There's different approaches you could take. For example, instead of `_validate_data` you could have `_extract_id` which returns `None` when the `data` is invalid, otherwise an `id_`, which you would then check, so something like:

```
id_ = _extract_id(data)
if id_ is None:
    return Response({'message': 'Valid Album id is required'})
else:
    # do the rest of the stuff
```

You must decide what makes more sense given the rest of your code and any standards you are following.

As a quick aside, this doesn't seem like a post to me, because it seems like you are just retrieving data, the album by id, POST is generally used to create new resource.